# OneOffTasks are not getting persisted after reboot

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an isolated OneOffTask

```
Task task = new OneoffTask.Builder()
            .setService(GCMTestService.class)
            .setExecutionWindow(0, 30)
            .setTag(GCMTestService.TAG)
            .setUpdateCurrent(false)
            .setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();

    gcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);
```

with .setPersisted(true)
As per docs [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/Task.Builder#setPersisted(boolean)) this should mean that the task should persist after a reboot, but that isn't the case. Periodic Tasks do persist, but not OneOffTasks.

I do have the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` perm in manifest as mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

As I've read in this [GitHub tutorial](https://github.com/filipproch/gcmnetworkmanager-android-example), you have to check in your service/task whether your app is configured/setup and you can eventually remove all the tasks here.

Use the code below together with the example provided to schedule a OneOff task from your Activity, Fragment, anywhere:

`MyTaskService.scheduleOneOff(context);`

**And the code below to schedule repeating task that persists after reboot:**

**`MyTaskService.scheduleRepeat(context);`**

Hope this helps!